# How to put matrix from specific sheet and cell from excel to matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, vba

I have problem with my code. I have been doing my task using VBA Excel and Matlab. and then I want to put my matrix from Excel to Matlab.  But my code does not work as expected.

```
MLPutMatrix "jum_kel", Range("D17")
MLPutMatrix "prob_mut", Range("D18")
MLPutMatrix "prob_co", Range("D19")
MLPutMatrix "uk_pop", Range("D20")
```

How do you code to put a matrix from a specific sheet and cell?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code, it should work fine provided you have the spreadsheetlink toolbox, the addin loaded in excel and a reference added in vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is MLPutMatrix is a command you run from Excel? I'm not familiar with it. Moving data from Excel to Matlab can be done simply from within Matlab using the `xlsread` command. The docs explain how to use it. http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/xlsread.html

Might this work for you?

Comment: MLPutMatrix is a command that is part of the Spreadsheet Link EX toolbox in Matlab which provide an excel addin that allows you to control matlab from vba. It has very different applications from xlsread. http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/exlink/